# NSStringFromClass() is invoked by UIApplicationMain(), but Foundation.h is not imported in main.m

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

**(a)** The 4th parameter in the *UIApplicationMain()* method is the method:
*NSStringFromClass()*
**(b)** *NSStringFromClass()* is found in *Foundation.h*
**(c)** The only import into **main.m** is *UIKit.h*.
**(d)** As best I can tell, *UIKit.h* does not extend the *Foundation.h*

So, why am I not getting an error when I compile **main.m**? *NSStringFromClass()* should be an unrecognized method?

Comment: If you preprocess the file (there is a menu item that does that), it'll show everything the compiler ends up compiling as `main.m`, including all imported headers.   If you start at the top of the file and search for `NSStringFromClass`, the definition *must* be the first instance found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the macro in the *prefix.pch file in your project supporting files ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry I did not try harder.

Answer (score 3):

Foundation is imported in the precompiled header that comes standard with every Xcode project:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the <x> target in the <x> project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```